# Why am I getting an error when I changed my network access to any IP address and even included my own?

Tags: mongodb, hosting, mongodb-atlas

Can I get help deploying my app with a database? This is the error I get. I've gone to network access and allowed from my IP address and any other IP address.. this is quite frustrating and discouraging!

```
*** You have failed to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.

Error: connect failed to replica set atlas-11aaj4-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00.xznp1.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.xznp1.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.xznp1.mongodb.net:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-15T03:02:54.206Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4333208, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"RSM host selection timeout","attr":{"replicaSet":"atlas-11aaj4-shard-0","error":"FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"nearest\" } for set atlas-11aaj4-shard-0"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-15T03:02:54.211Z"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23279,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"SSL peer certificate validation failed","attr":{"errorCode":"800B0101","error":"A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file."}}   
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-15T03:02:54.215Z"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23279,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"SSL peer certificate validation failed","attr":{"errorCode":"800B0101","error":"A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file."}}   
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

This is the url they gave me to connect to my cluster

```
 mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.xznp1.mongodb.net/test" --username adm
in-ayanda
```

Comment: Have you whitelisted your IP in the Atlas control panel?

Comment: Are you sure you want to publish the address and access credentials of your Atlas database here publicly‽